# Animation of several objects depend on main object

Tags: animation, rigging

I would like to animate a clothed human model. The human geometry is rigged, but I dont know how to add additional objects to the human rig.

I want the t-shirts and pants movement to follow the human's poses.

[image: rigged human geometry]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to parent multiple objects to the same armature. Simply repeat whichever method you used to parent the human to the rig on the clothing.

For example: Select the clothing and then shift select the rig and press "Ctrl + P" and then select "Armature Deform with Automatic Weights".